# Breaking encryption with hash value of password?

Tags: hash

Can you break an encrypted volume if you know the source code of the crypto-tool used and the hash value of the secret passphrase? Why is it not possible to just reverse engineer the passphrase verification process of the crypto-tool by tricking it with the extracted hash value?

Specifically I was thinking about the popular truecrypt program, dm-crypt and self-encrypting-drives. Is the sensitive data on a self-encrypted-drive in danger if the attacker is able to obtain / extract the whole source code programmed on the chip of the SED and also the hash value of the passphrase?

Answer (score 1):

A hash isn't used in encryption.  A key derivation function is used to turn a password in to a key and that key is used for decryption, not stored.  There should be no password hash.  Password hashes are stored for purposes of authentication where a password has to be compared to a previous input without the server knowing what the previous input was.

Comment: If no password is stored how comes that the program knows when to display "entered passphrase is wrong" message to the user and deny decryption? Why to prevent the attacker from extracting information from the crypto-chip of a SED? What information is so crucial? I mean when using truecrypt instead you rely on open source tool?!

Comment: @user3200534 - the easiest way would be to start the volume out with a known plain-text.  When you decrypt, you could simply check if it matches.  If not, then you know the key was wrong.  I don't know exactly how TrueCrypt does it, but there is no reason to store a hash of a password when dealing with encryption.  It would only serve to drastically weaken your security.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first, I only know about truecrypt. The password is not really hashed, but rather send through a key derivation algorithm (ok, in my opinion, it is just a different hashing-algorithm, so I'll continue calling it hash). So to answer your first question:

Yes, if you know the hash of the password, it would be possible to decrypt the data. I believe that is a big potential risk in all SED implementations, and never really satisfactory communicated by the vendors.

Truecrypt uses a different approach. In TC, first the encryption key for the symmetric encryption of the data is generated (using randomized data). Then, the "hashed" password is used to encrypt the encryption key. The key derivation method and the encrypted encryption key are stored in the volume header, but not the hashed password itself. If you enter a password now to unlock the drive, this password is "hashed" according to the key derivation method used for the volume. With the result, TC will decrypt the header and look for a specific value, simplified an "OK". So if decryption with the supplied password yields the "OK" bit, truecrypt knows the password is correct. So there is no need to store the hashed password. The hash will simply be generated every time you try to unlock and challenged against a known value.

Now, as stated before, about SEDs I am not so sure and often I doubt that the manufacturer think that far. A whitepaper from Seagate on their SEDs at least suggests that the hashed password is stored "somewhere". It is unclear if it is possible to acquire this hash with dismanteling of the drive or hardware hacking.